# How to connect to my http://localhost web server from MEmu Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to connect to my http://localhost web server from MEmu Android emulator for development with android studio and MVC or PHP web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use IP address `http://10.0.3.2` in your application.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't access localhost via `http://10.0.3.2:<hostport>` instead I had to use: `http://10.0.2.2:<hostport>`

Answer (score 0):

Set MEmu network to bridged mode.

After that I was able to connect the host PC on `http://192.168.x.y:zzzz/`